# How do I delete the spaces (trailing and ending) using a python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

This is my string "INDUSTRIAL, PARKS, PROPERTY"
I want to delete the spaces trailing parks, property.
I want the output as "INDUSTRIAL,PARKS,PROPERTY"

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python remove spaces from line", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 0):

For your example you can do:

```
strr = "INDUSTRIAL, PARKS, PROPERTY"
','.join(strr.split(', '))
```

Otherwise if you have something like:

```
strr = "INDUSTRIAL, PARKS,    PROPERTY"
','.join([s.strip() for s in strr.split(', ')])
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but how do I remove the ending space also? strr = "INDUSTRIAL, PARKS,PROPERTY  " (note the ending space after Property)

Comment: use `.strip()` on the initial string